# Google Datastore and Firestore - can you use emojis as an ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

If you have a string as your entity/document id, can you safely use emojis or foreign language characters as the id?

Can you use one of these as an Id? Is there some risk if you do?

```
book
كتاب
書
```

Comment: Print this `console.log('\u{1F600}')` this is how string looks like in database if you assign it as  emoji.

Comment: This is an Arabic word you posted `\u{643}\u{62A}\u{627}\u{628}`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  No, there is no risk (other than causing confusion to those attempting to read and interpret things). All strings in Firestore are UTF-8 strings as you can see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

In fact, I tweeted about this a long time ago.

https://twitter.com/codingdoug/status/961302822997213184?lang=en